# Access to Browser's localStorage from Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, browser, java-native-interface, local-storage

I am working on a SingleSignOn application where the sign on is shared between app accessible via Browser and separate Java Rich Internet Application (RIA). The idea is once user logs in to app A via Browser, a certain key-value pair is stored in Browser's (IE in our case) local storage. This certain key-value pair needs to be then retrieved by application B (Java's RIA) to ease the login (and predominantly - the onboarding process).

I have evaluated following:

1. Directly accessing localStorage on Hard Drive

   - this location cannot be determined across entire client-base and seems *fragile* to me (i.e. it's not guaranteed it will not change in future IE releases)
2. Using JNI to call Windows native WinInet libraries (i.e. InternetGetCookie)

   - this seems to access the cookie store and not the local storage which is where sought after value is stored

Note: I do not have control over where the key-value pair is stored, as that's handled by a 3rd party library, and that library stores values in the localStorage exclusively.

So the question is, how do I access the IE's localStorage via Java, or via Windows native libraries that I can call with i.e. JNI? Or perhaps there's an alternative I have not thought of?